# Can't disconnect nbd device

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, devices, block-device

I made an .qcow2 image and mounted it as described here:

https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/how-to-mount-a-qcow2-disk-image-that-does-not-contain-an-ubuntu-lvm-installation

But I have a problem with the 2 last steps when I'm trying to disconnect my nbd device using commands:

```
#Disconnect the image from the NBD device
qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0;
#Unload the NBD module
rmmod nbd;
```

For /dev/nbd0 I get the following output:
/dev/nbd3 disconnected
But when I do:

```
lsblk
```

nbd3 is still there.
And I can't execute

```
rmmod nbd
```

because of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to **unmount the image**.

Here the complete process I use:

```
umount /dev/mapper/vg_name--lv_name
vgchange -a n lv_name
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0  # or 1, 2, etc.
nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0 # or 1, 2, etc.
vgchange -ay
modprobe -r nbd
```

Comment: What is vg_name? I don't set it up while setting up the image.

Comment: vg_name = volume group name for LVM. Use `vgs` or `vgdisplay`to show the volume group name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I did it without vgchange. It turned out that I somehow managed to block processes and after a reboot your method worked.